# svn export Zend Framework 1?

Tags: svn, zend-framework

I was trying to setup an old project that uses zf1. The setup script failed trying to execute this command.

```
svn export http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/branches/release-1.12/library/Zend /checkoutfolder
```

As per this blog, https://framework.zend.com/blog/2013-03-27-zf1-git-migration.html, only versions prior to 1.12 are available in Subversion repository.

I am ok with using version 1.11. Can someone please tell me what the above command should look like? Replacing "release-1.12" with "release-1.11" fails.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the svn repository was taken down, you can use the git one and clone the latest release to the checkout folder.

Answer (score 0):

They've moved over to git and are hosting ZF1 at github.

https://framework.zend.com/blog/2013-03-27-zf1-git-migration.html

https://github.com/zendframework/zf1

Generally, I download the latest (probably last) version from their website and go from there.

http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/framework/downloads

Good luck!